# React: Passing function as prop but window undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to clean up some code and make more reusable components. 
 In this approach, I extracted some a piece of code and made it a child component.  While passing in some functions from a parent to various children components, I keep getting `window is undefined` when I try to pass in functions from that parent that have window in them.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
**inside a parent component** 

checkHierarchy: function() {

   window.eventLog("free");
}

render: function() {

   return ( 
        <ChildComponent 
            checkHierarchy = {this.checkHierarchy}
        />

   );

}
```

Comment: But `window` is a global namespace. You don't have to pass it down to make it accessible by children components.

Comment: Does it happen during browser run or tests? If latest you can try use `global` in your test.